# Goflex 1TB external hardrive not recognized

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate GOflex 1TB external hard drive and I cannot get it to mount. I built a new PC a few days ago that has USB 3.0. I wanted to swap some files from my old PC to my new PC and I cannot get it to mount now in the old PC. The old PC utilizes USB 2.0 ports and the hard drive mounted fine until I mounted it to the new PC's USB 3.0 slots. Now it will only work on USB 3.0 and windows will not even recognize it when it's connected to a USB 2.0 slot. Both PC's are running Windows 7 64 bit professional and both have ASUS motherboards. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, does the PC with USB 3.0 also have USB 2.0 ports?  If so, does it work when plugged into that PC's USB 2.0 ports?

Answer (score 1):

You may have already tried some of these, but it doesn't hurt to try them again:

1. Reboot the PCs and try again.
2. If the drive has an optional power supply, be sure to plug it in (USB 3.0 supplies more power, so a portable/bus-powered drive might not need its external power adapter when plugged into a USB 3.0 port.)
3. If you have a cable with a second USB connector pigtail, plug both USB connectors into different USB ports (preferably on separate USB headers).
4. Try hooking up the drive to different USB 2.0 ports on both PCs.
5. Try hooking up the drive to a different PC's USB 2.0 ports.
6. Try a different USB cable.
7. Try removing the drive from its GoFlex dock and reattaching it.
8. Mount the drive on the USB 3.0 PC, run chkdsk, and eject it using the *Safely Remove Hardware* utility, then try it again on the USB 2.0 PC.
9. Click the Start button, start typing *Disk Management*, and click the option to *Create and Format hard disk partitions*. Confirm that the drive is in the list and is Online. If not, you might need to right-click on it and import it (though this normally should not be necessary for external drives).
10. Worst-case scenario: remove the GoFlex dock and temporarily connect the drive directly to the PC's motherboard and power supply. (One nice feature of the GoFlex drives is that removing the GoFlex connector exposes the hard drive's SATA power and data connectors.)